# BigQuery: Create a table from arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I want to create a table with two columns from two different arrays.

> Array1: [1,2,3]
>
> Array2: [11,12,13]

Required Table:

[image: two columns, 3 rows]

By using this query, I got 1 row

```
SELECT 
[1,2,3] AS S1,
[11,12,13] AS S2
```

[image: 1 row, 2 columns]

I tried UNNEST, but got cartesian product

```
SELECT S1, S2
FROM 
UNNEST([1,2,3]) AS S1,
UNNEST([11,12,13]) AS S2
```

[image: 2 columns, 9 rows - cartesian product]

How can I create required table (pic 1) from arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method uses a join and `WITH OFFSET`:

```
SELECT S1, S2, o1, o2
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) s1 WITH OFFSET o1 LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST([11, 12, 13]) S2 WITH OFFSET o2
     ON o1 = o2;
```

It would be nice if `UNNEST()` in BigQuery supported multiple arguments, as some other databases do.

Comment: Amazing :) @Gordon Bro, I am really thankful. Stay blessed :)